# File API - Blob to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, websocket

I'm trying to do some experiment with HTML5, WebSocket and File API.
I'm using the Tomcat7 WebSocket implementation. 
I'm able to send and received text messages from the servlet. What I want to do now is to send from the servlet to the client JSON objects, but I want to avoid text message in order to skip the JSON.parse (or similar) on the client, so I'm trying to send binary messages.
The servlet part is really simple:

```
String s = "{arr : [1,2]}";
CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.wrap(s);      
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();      
getWsOutbound().writeBinaryMessage(encoder.encode(cbuf));
getWsOutbound().flush();
```

After this message, on the client I see that I received a binary frame, that is converted to a Blob object (http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob).
The question is: is it possible to get the JSON object from the Blob?
I took a look at the FileReader interface (http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface), and I used code like this to inspect what the FileReader can do (the first line creates a brand new Blob, so you can test on the fly if you want):

```
var b = new Blob([{"test": "toast"}], {type : "application/json"});
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(evt) {
    var res = evt.target.result;
    console.log("onload",arguments, res, typeof res);
};
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(b);
```

using all the "readAs..." methods that I saw on the File Reader implementation (I'm using Chrome 22). Anyway I didn't find something useful.

Did you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: How do you think you can send JSON-strings as binary messages? JSON is just a encoding for objects, and you can't really send the implementation-dependent binary structure get around some `parse` function.

Comment: yeah you're right, it doesn't make any sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're doing is conceptually wrong.  JSON is a string representation of an object, not an object itself.  So, when you send a binary representation of JSON over the wire, you're sending a binary representation of the string.  There's no way to get around parsing JSON on the client side to convert a JSON string to a JavaScript Object.

You absolutely should always send JSON as text to the client, and you should always call JSON.parse.  Nothing else is going to be easy for you.

Comment: As I said to Bergi, and as you said at the beginning, the question is conceptually wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Cool! I could have asked the same question.

Comment: Question is not wrong. One legitimate case is when server can respond with different content-types, e.g. Excel file in case of success or JSON in case of error.

Answer (score 36):

You should have tried [readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) instead of `readAsArrayBuffer()` (JSON is text in the end).

You've also missed to stringify the object (convert to JSON text)

```
var b = new Blob([JSON.stringify({"test": "toast"})], {type : "application/json"}),
    fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.result))
};

fr.readAsText(b);
```

Answer (score 23):

To convert `Blob`/`File` that contains JSON data to a JavaScript object use it:

```js
JSON.parse(await blob.text());
```

---

The example:

*Select a JSON file, then you can use it in the browser's console (`json` object).*

```js
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.accept = "application/json";
document.body.prepend(input);
input.addEventListener("change", async event => {
    const json = JSON.parse(await input.files[0].text());

    console.log("json", json);
    globalThis.json = json;
});
```

Comment: Note: to get access to `json` variable in the console right here, you need to change the console's context from "top" to "IFrame".

Comment: BTW, you can run this example code on any site (in the browser console) where you need to "load" content of a JSON file for some purpose. If the input will be hidden by CSS, you can open the file picker by `input.click();`.

Comment: This won't work in chrome if the blob is >=.5Gb, since it's impossible to create a string that big.

Answer (score 2):

```
let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = e => {
        if (e.target.readyState === 2) {
          let res = {}
          if (window.TextDecoder) {
            const enc = new TextDecoder('utf-8')
            res = JSON.parse(enc.decode(new Uint8Array(e.target.result))) //转化成json对象
          } else {
            res = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(e.target.result)))
          }

          console.info('import-back:: ', res)


        }
      }

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(response)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include some context for what your code does and/or how it answers the question. This makes it much more useful for those who come across the same issue later on.