# reading a web api blob into a string that I can send as part of a json object to the server and turn back into a file

Tags: c#, json, html, file, encoding

i'm trying to turn a wav file into a string I can send to the server as a part of a json object, so that on the server I can turn that string back into a file.

i have tried to use readAsBinaryString and read as text, can't get past error in reading the string into a byte array.

```
 reader.onloadend = saveMedia;
 reader.readAsText(Blob);
 //reader.readAsBinaryString(Blob); also tried.
```

then the callback sends an ajax request with an object holding the string in "reader.result" and on the server i tried things like:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
byte[] BinaryData = encoding.GetBytes(stringFromRequest);
```

the answers to this question below seem to be that this should not be done. but i really want to do it this way because of another tool I am using (breeze js). don't want to use a separate post action with a file data type.

releted:
[File API - Blob to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786818/file-api-blob-to-json)

Comment: sounds like what you might want (though I'm not totally clear on your use case here) is some encoding of binary data to text; eg base64?

Comment: that is the direction I am exploring at the moment. using btoa to encode. the use case: a user can record himself, then listen to the recording and choose to save it to a persistent database, the recording itself has an entity associated with it that breeze js knows about. this entity will hold the binary data when it is sent to the server, but also other information about the recording (general entity data).

Comment: yes! that works great. i'll post this as the answer unless you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way that works:

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = afterRead;
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

function afterRead() {
// convert binary string to base64 for a safe transfer to the server.       
   entity.BinaryProp = window.btoa(reader.result);       
}
```

on the server-side:

```
string BinaryString = (string)entityInfo.UnmappedValuesMap["BinaryProp"];
byte[] BinaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(BinaryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is great, but there is a simpler way.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = afterRead;
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);               // Use this function instead

function afterRead() {
    entity.BinaryProp = reader.result;    //result is already a base64 string!
}
```

See documentation here: [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: Not quite... `FileReader.readAsDataURL` will convert the blob in its data representation for HTML tags. Something like `data:[mimetype];base64,[B64]`. You would then need to extrapolate the base64 string from that, if you only need that. The accepted answer IMHO is cleaner in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)`, this encode blob to base64, which can safely upload to server by API.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = () => {
    let thumbnail = reader.result;
    console.log(thumbnail)
    //send to API
};
```

Comment: Not quite... `FileReader.readAsDataURL` will convert the blob in its data representation for HTML tags. Something like `data:[mimetype];base64,[B64]`. You would then need to extrapolate the base64 string from that, if you only need that. The accepted answer IMHO is cleaner in doing so.