# How to properly implement "photo.service"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4. And when I try to output an image, there is a 404 error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> Image (async)
>   DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty   @   platform-browser.es5.js:2895
>   AnimationRenderer.setProperty @   animations.es5.js:534
>   DebugRenderer2.setProperty    @   core.es5.js:13740
>   setElementProperty    @   core.es5.js:9401
>   checkAndUpdateElementValue    @   core.es5.js:9320
>   checkAndUpdateElementInline   @   core.es5.js:9254
>   checkAndUpdateNodeInline  @   core.es5.js:12337
>   checkAndUpdateNode    @   core.es5.js:12284
>   debugCheckAndUpdateNode   @   core.es5.js:13141
>   debugCheckRenderNodeFn    @   core.es5.js:13120
>   (anonymous)   @   ProfileComponent.html:8
>   debugUpdateRenderer   @   core.es5.js:13105
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12256
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execComponentViewsAction  @   core.es5.js:12531
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12257
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execComponentViewsAction  @   core.es5.js:12531
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12257
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execComponentViewsAction  @   core.es5.js:12531
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12257
>   callWithDebugContext  @   core.es5.js:13467
>   debugCheckAndUpdateView   @   core.es5.js:13007
>   ViewRef_.detectChanges    @   core.es5.js:10174
>   (anonymous)   @   core.es5.js:4812 ApplicationRef_.tick   @   core.es5.js:4812
>   (anonymous)   @   core.es5.js:4684 ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:388
>   onInvoke  @   core.es5.js:3890 ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:387
>   Zone.run  @   zone.js:138 NgZone.run  @   core.es5.js:3821
>   next  @   core.es5.js:4684 schedulerFn    @   core.es5.js:3635
>   SafeSubscriber.**tryOrUnsub   @   Subscriber.js:238
>   SafeSubscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:185
>   Subscriber._next  @   Subscriber.js:125
>   Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:89 Subject.next   @   Subject.js:55
>   EventEmitter.emit @   core.es5.js:3621 checkStable    @   core.es5.js:3855
>   onLeave   @   core.es5.js:3934 onInvokeTask   @   core.es5.js:3884
>   ZoneDelegate.invokeTask   @   zone.js:420 Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:188
>   ZoneTask.invokeTask   @   zone.js:496 invokeTask  @   zone.js:1540
>   globalZoneAwareCallback   @   zone.js:1566 error (async)
>
>   customScheduleGlobal  @   zone.js:1666
>   ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @   zone.js:407 onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:297
>   ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @   zone.js:401
>   Zone.scheduleTask @   zone.js:232 Zone.scheduleEventTask  @   zone.js:258
>   (anonymous)   @   zone.js:1831 (anonymous)    @   http.es5.js:1274
>   Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:171
>   Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:159
>   ConnectableObservable.connect @   ConnectableObservable.js:39
>   RefCountOperator.call @   ConnectableObservable.js:108
>   Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:156
>   AuthService._handleResponse   @   auth.service.ts:592
>   AuthService.request   @   auth.service.ts:574
>   AuthService.get   @   auth.service.ts:498
>   PhotoService.getPhotos    @   photo.service.ts:15
>   ProfileComponent.loadPhotos   @   profile.component.ts:78
>   ProfileComponent.ngOnInit @   profile.component.ts:62
>   checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @   core.es5.js:10843
>   checkAndUpdateNodeInline  @   core.es5.js:12341
>   checkAndUpdateNode    @   core.es5.js:12284
>   debugCheckAndUpdateNode   @   core.es5.js:13141
>   debugCheckDirectivesFn    @   core.es5.js:13082
>   (anonymous)   @   ProfileComponent_Host.html:1
>   debugUpdateDirectives @   core.es5.js:13067
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12251
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execComponentViewsAction  @   core.es5.js:12531
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12257
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction   @   core.es5.js:12557
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12252
>   callViewAction    @   core.es5.js:12599
>   execComponentViewsAction  @   core.es5.js:12531
>   checkAndUpdateView    @   core.es5.js:12257
>   callWithDebugContext  @   core.es5.js:13467
>   debugCheckAndUpdateView   @   core.es5.js:13007
>   ViewRef_.detectChanges    @   core.es5.js:10174
>   (anonymous)   @   core.es5.js:4812 ApplicationRef_.tick   @   core.es5.js:4812
>   (anonymous)   @   core.es5.js:4684 ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:388
>   onInvoke  @   core.es5.js:3890 ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:387
>   Zone.run  @   zone.js:138 NgZone.run  @   core.es5.js:3821
>   next  @   core.es5.js:4684 schedulerFn    @   core.es5.js:3635
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub   @   Subscriber.js:238
>   SafeSubscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:185
>   Subscriber._next  @   Subscriber.js:125
>   Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:89 Subject.next   @   Subject.js:55
>   EventEmitter.emit @   core.es5.js:3621 checkStable    @   core.es5.js:3855
>   onHasTask @   core.es5.js:3903 ZoneDelegate.hasTask   @   zone.js:441
>   ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @   zone.js:461
>   Zone.*updateTaskCount @   zone.js:285 Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:205
>   drainMicroTaskQueue   @   zone.js:595 Promise.then (async)
>
>   scheduleMicroTask @   zone.js:578
>   ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @   zone.js:410
>   Zone.scheduleTask @   zone.js:232 Zone.scheduleMicroTask  @   zone.js:252
>   scheduleResolveOrReject   @   zone.js:862
>   ZoneAwarePromise.then @   zone.js:962
>   PlatformRef*.*bootstrapModuleWithZone @   core.es5.js:4537
>   PlatformRef*.bootstrapModule  @   core.es5.js:4522
>   (anonymous)   @   main.ts:11 ./src/main.ts    @   main.bundle.js:1057
>   __webpack_require**   @   inline.bundle.js:55 0   @   main.bundle.js:1065
>   **webpack_require**   @   inline.bundle.js:55 webpackJsonpCallback    @   inline.bundle.js:26
>   (anonymous)   @   main.bundle.js:1

What have I done wrong?

photo.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Photo} from '../../models/photo.model';
import {handleError} from "../../shared/functions";
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PhotoService{
    constructor(
        private _authService:AuthService
    ){ 
    }

    getPhotos(){
        return this._authService.get('photos')
            .map(result => result.json())  
    }

}
```

photo.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../../services/auth/auth.service";
import { PhotoService} from "../../../services/photo/photo.service";
import { Photo} from "../../../models/photo.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'photo',
  templateUrl: './photo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo.component.scss'],
  providers: [PhotoService]
})

export class PhotoComponent implements OnInit {

  photos: Array<Photo>;

  filteredPhotos =[];

  constructor(
    protected authService:AuthService,
    private servPhoto: PhotoService
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPhotos();
  }

  private loadPhotos() {
    let filteredPhotos;
    if (this.servPhoto) {
      this.servPhoto.getPhotos().subscribe(
        photo => {
          if(!this.authService.currentUserData) {    
            return; 
          }
          this.photos = photo;
          this.filteredPhotos = this.photos.filter(
            (photo) => photo.users_id ==  this.authService.currentUserData.id
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }

}
```

photo.model.ts:

```
export class Photo{
    constructor(
        public users_id: number,
        public photo: Blob
    ) { }
}
```

photo.component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="authService.currentUserData">
   <img class="img" *ngFor="let photo of filteredPhotos" src="{{ photo.photo }}">
</div>
```

And here is the JSON itself:

```
[{"users_id":36,"photo":"/photos/original/missing.png"},

{"users_id":1,"photo":"/photos/original/missing.png"},

{"users_id":1428,"photo":"/photos/original/missing.png"}]
```

Comment: can you post angular.json or angular-cli.json file as well?

Comment: @Sanoj_V posted

Comment: Please check i have posted an answer look there

Comment: 404 means file not found. You didn't get the correct URL for your photos. Maybe try adding `assets` before your sources in your JSON, the CLI usually creates an assets folder when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

You have `src="{{ photo.photo }}` and your JSON has `"photo":"/photos/original/missing.png"`

Your error: `GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)` is simply telling you the photo doesn't exist.

> What have I done wrong?

Nothing *wrong*. The code is simply trying to load the image that isn't present. If you want the 404 to go away make sure an image is present at the mentioned url provided by the JSON.

Comment: But there is an image there

Answer (score 0):

I think your service is giving out json while your class is expecting a Blob data type.

Comment: and what do you suggest I do if the picture is in the "Blob" format?

Comment: You can try casting the json output as Blob. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786818/file-api-blob-to-json

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

If you are getting proper response in `filteredPhotos`

```
<div *ngIf="authService.currentUserData">
<div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let photo of filteredPhotos" >
   <img class="img"  [src]="photo.photo">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting response as file?? http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png ??

Comment: so the issue is that you dont have file downloaded on system

Comment: I get the answer as " text/html"

Comment: it should be "image/png'

Comment: something I do not understand "so the issue is that you dont have file downloaded on system "

Comment: ok first thing. you are getting these files using api right?. that you have created a service to get file json?? not the file data.

Comment: You have to read file using api. because right now you are checking at client side-->
localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png but  it does not exist here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate folder inside **angular.json** or **angular-cli.json** file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "photos"   //<==== you have to add this folder source here     
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
        "./assets/sass/material-style.scss",
        "./assets/css/style.css",
        "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js",
        "../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {
    }
  },
  "warnings": {
    "typescriptMismatch": false
  }
}
```

then stop your **ng** or **npm** and run again.

Now **ng serve** or **npm start**
This solve your problem

Comment: @user10254427 have you checked??